# How to dedicate server to MySQL for max performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, centos

I am using MariaDB 10.5, I see this in MySQLTuner report

Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.

How do I do this?

My server is on Centos 8.

Comment: Don't worry about it while you are getting started.  It may be that you can have everything on the same server without any performance problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this startetd as comment, but it git to big

This only means that the database server should run on a hardware where it doesn't share Memory, CPU and Hard drive with other services like webserver for example, or run in a virtual hardware with other virtual environments, which share memory and CPUs.

The biggest Problems you will face are huge amount of data or a lot of parallel connections, which will need be addressed by better hardware or one of the cloud services.

Till then check the error logs of mysql and server, if something is a miss like to small temporary tables, not enough connection and lots more, you will find log entry about it and find a solution by searching for that error or warning.

On a final point the settings depend a lot on what you are doing have  you for example huge inner joins and 6 or 7 of them your settings will be nit the same as other scenarios.

Check your query with EXPLAIN and see that teh indexes are correct set, that will help much more than tweaking one or other parameter.